# How to find first parent element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Conside below html -

```
<div class="container1">
   <div class="container2">
      <div class="container3">
         <div class="container4">
             <div class="element">
             ...
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

if I want to get `<div class="element">` element and I have reference to the `container1`. In jquery what I do is,

```
$(".container1").find(".element")
```

instead of -

```
$(".container1").children().children().children().find(".element")
```

This is process to find any child element when I have reference to any of the parent element. But instead when I have reference to a child element and want to get parent element then every time I have to go one level up -

```
$(".element").parent().parent().parent().parent()
```

and I can't do like this -

```
$(".element").findParent()
```

I have not come across any method like findParent() in jquery. Is there which I am not aware of? Or is it not there for some reason?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$(".element").parents();
```

will give all parents of `.element`*(including `html` and `body`)*

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/509/)**

To find any specific parent, suppose `container1` then

```
$('.element').parents('.container1')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/508/)**

jQuery [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents) generally find all parents, but if you passed a selector then it will search for that.

Comment: That's perfect, why I didn't came to know about that.

Comment: Dang, you beat me to posting this. :P

Answer (score 14):

just use

```
$(".element").closest('#container1');
```

if no ancestor with that `id` is found then

`$(".element").closest('#container1').length` will be `0`

Answer (score 1):

To get the first parent personally I use the following construction:

```
var count_parents = $(".element").parents().length;
$(".element").parents().eq(count_parents - 1);
```

Hope, it will be helpful for someone.