# Select parent of div - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and don't know Why this code doesn't work. I'm trying to select parent of `b` which is `a`.

```
<div id='a'> This is div a 
    <div id='b'>
        This is div b
    </div>
</div>
```

Why this code is giving me undefined, I'm expecting a?

```
console.log($('#b.parent').attr('id'));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find first parent element in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227133/how-to-find-first-parent-element-in-jquery)

Comment: `$('#b').closest('div').prop('id');`

Comment: `document.getElementById('b').parentNode.id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZELVK/1/)

You are using wrong selector use, `$('#b').parent().attr('id');` instead.

You can also replace `attr` with `prop`, it's slightly faster.

`$('#b').parent().prop('id');`

Answer (score 1):

Then use parent()

```
  $('#b').parent().attr('id')
```